# How to POST radio button value in php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am doing project using Zend framework. here within the form I add field using radio buttons.  after the form post. it doesn't send that radio button value(but other fields (eg -text field can post)). this is my code in the view.

```
<form class="custom" method="post">

   <?php
     foreach ($answers as $answer) {
         echo '<input name="q_answer" value="'.$answer.'" type="radio" >'.$answer;
     }
   ?>
    <input class="small secondary button" type="submit" value="  Ok  ">
</form>
```

this is my code within controller

```
if($request->isPost()){
   $ans = $_POST['q_answer'];
}
```

so when I post the form. it gives `Undefined index: q_answer` error. what is the wrong. please help me.( within the controller I print posted values using `var_dump` but 'q_answer' value not available)

Comment: Did you actually select one of the radio buttons? Otherwise the value may not be in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If no option is selected this field is not appear in `$_POST`. So you should first check with `isset()` if it is present and the try to process. And while you are using ZF, you should use `getPost()`instead of digging directly in `$_POST`:

```
$ans = getPost( 'q_answer', 'default-value-if-no-element-is-found' );
```